# iOS6 - Social Framework - how does SLComposeViewController fallback to TWTweetComposeViewController for iOS5?

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I have a piece of piece of twitter sharing codes that works fine for iOS6 but I need the application to fall back nicely to iOS5 too...

It looks like this:

```
- (void) shareOnTwitter
{
    if([SLComposeViewController instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(isAvailableForServiceType)] != nil)
    {
        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
        {
            NSLog(@"twitter available");
            SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
            [composeViewController setInitialText:self.sharingText];
            [self.sharingController presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"twitter not available!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // SLComposeViewController not available, this is most likely <iOS6, what to do here?
    }
}
```

SO, how do I fall back nicely in iOS5 (I assume I need TWTweetComposeViewController) so that I can use the native twitter in iOS5 too?

EDIT:
At the end I am still lazy to fallback to TWTweetComposeViewController so I decided to simply fallback in this sequence: iOS6 native tweet -> installed twitter app -> web url.
This is the function I put together, hope it helps someone:

```
+(BOOL)isSocialFrameworkAvailable
{
     // whether the iOS6 Social framework is available?
    return NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil;
}

- (void) shareOnTwitterWithText:(NSString*)text andURL:(NSString*)url andImageName:(NSString*)imageName
{
    // prepare the message to be shared
    NSString *combineMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", text, url];
    NSString *escapedMessage = [combineMessage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *appURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://post?message=%@", escapedMessage];

    if([SocialManager isSocialFrameworkAvailable] && [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        // user has setup the iOS6 twitter account

        SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [composeViewController setInitialText:text];
        if([UIImage imageNamed:imageName])
        {
            [composeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        }
        if(url)
        {
            [composeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        }
        [self.sharingController presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        // else, we have to fallback to app or browser
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]])
        {
            // twitter app available!
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];
        }
        else
        {
            // worse come to worse, open twitter page in browser
            NSString *web = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%@", escapedMessage];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:web]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to weak link the Twitter and Social frameworks, and check in your code whether a framework is available.  Weak linking is done like this:

- Click on your project in XCode, select your Target, Build Phases, then Link Binary with Libraries
- Make sure Social.framework is set to Optional if you want to run this app on iOS 5.x or earlier
- Make sure Twitter.framework is set to Optional if you want to run this on iOS 4.x or earlier

I like to create simple class functions to determine which frameworks are available.  That could look something like this:

```
+(BOOL)isTwitterAvailable {
   return NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController") != nil;
}

+(BOOL)isSocialAvailable {
    return NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil;
}
```

Your "tweet" code could look something like this:

```
if ([SomeClass isSocialAvailable]) {
   // code to tweet with SLComposeViewController
} else if ([SomeClass isTwitterAvailable]) {
   // code to tweet with TWTweetComposeViewController
} else {
   // Twitter not available, or open a url like https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=tweet%20text
}
```

Comment: thanks chris! your answer confirmed to me that I need to include the Twitter framework which is not available in my latest Xcode version now.. i need to get it..thanks!

Comment: @chris can you use TWTweetComposeViewController in iOS6 or what are the benefits from using SLComposeViewController in iOS6?

Comment: I don't know if there is an advantage, and I'm willing to bet `SLComposeViewController` just wraps `TWTweetComposeViewController`.  Also, I could imagine that Apple will eventually deprecate `TWTweetComposeViewController` in favour of `SLComposeViewController`.

Comment: SLComposeViewController provides the same interface to share on Facebook, twitter and weibo at the same time so it is definitely a better choice than TWTweetComposeViewController? THe only sad thing is SLComposeViewController only works in iOS6 and doesn't work in iOS5...so a fallback is needed

Answer (score 7):

Not sure how expensive these runtime operations are, but no harm in doing this since there is zero chance of this status changing while the app is running:

```
+ (BOOL)isTwitterAvailable
{
    static BOOL available;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        available = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController") != nil;        
    });
    return available;
}
+ (BOOL)isSocialAvailable
{
    static BOOL available;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        available = NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil;        
    });
    return available;
}
```

Comment: Why the -1??  Fyi to loop over both checks 1000x on an iPhone 4S is something like 0.000816 sec with the method I offered, and 0.011595 sec with the other method.  I don't know if anyone is calling this a ton, but why keep resolving the class over and over when it's not going to change while your app is running?  It seems like bad form to keep resolving the same thing over and over when it's so easy to store the result once.

Comment: There is always harm in premature optimization